# Is there a way to set ptr record for my openshift application

Tags: email, smtp, openshift

I'm using openshift for my django application. All mail that I send from my application are send to spam. I googled that I need to set a ptr record. Since openshift doesn't have SMTP server, I created one on dreamhost and used it for sending mail. Since dreamhost will set ptr records only for unique ip addresses, I can not set ptr.
So my question is, how can I send mail from my project hosted on openshift that won't end up in spam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like http://www.mailgun.com/. Much easier to integrate into apps and never need to worry about stuff ending up in spam. Using aws or openshift like platforms never works well for mail as they depend very much on IP Address (from what I learned). I don't think you can get a static IP for openshift online (if that is what you are using).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. Is there a free alternative?

Comment: I don't of any such services which are free (mandrill,sendgrid,etc). The 10K free mails per month is good enough for most dev works though.